# How to apply a R output as a LaTex section?

Tags: r, latex, knitr, sweave

Suppose I have a R chunk in x.rnw file such like

```
<<section1, echo=F>>=
> x <- "A_B_C"
> result <- paste0("\\section {",gsub("_","\\\\_",x),"}")
> cat(result)
\section {A\_B\_C}
@
```

How to let the output `\section {A\_B\_C}` to be executable as a `\section` during **Sweave** or **knitr**?

Comment: set chunk option `results='asis'`